# Why Vue Component Won't Update On Select Change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a form that changes some text within a vue component when a select box is changed. I've created a highly minimized version of this in jsfiddle to show the issue I'm experiencing:

https://jsfiddle.net/ywaug7ft/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<h5>Select a gender</h5>
  <select v-model="gender">
    <option disabled="disabled" value>Select...</option>
    <option value="1">Male</option>
    <option value="2">Female</option>
    <option value="3">Couple</option>
  </select>
  <div></div>
  <detail-component v-for="(detail, index) in details" :data="detail" :index="index"></detail-component>

  {{details}}
</div>

<template id="details">
   <div>
     <h4><span v-if="item.gender == 3 && index == 0">Her</span><span
                v-else-if="item.gender == 3 && index == 1">His</span><span v-else>Your</span> Health Details</h4>
     <div>Index: {{index}}</div>
     <div>Gender: {{item.gender}}</div>
   </div>
</template>
```

Vue:

```
Vue.component('detail-component', {
  template: '#details',
  props: ['data', 'index'],
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        gender: this.data.gender
      }
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    gender: '',
    details: [],
    options: {
        gender: {
        "1": "Single Female",
        "2": "Single Male",
        "3": "Couple"
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    gender: function(val) {
      this.details = [];
      if (val == 1) {
        this.details.push({gender: 1});
      } else if (val == 2) {
        this.details.push({gender: 2});
      } else if (val == 3) {
        this.details.push({gender: 3}, {gender: 3});
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Basically, when I select `female` or `male` from the dropdown, my vue component should update the h tag to say `Your Details`. When I select `couple`, my view component should update to say `Her Details` and `His Details`. However, it's not updating the first index to `Her` but instead maintains `Your`.

Take a look at the jsfiddle and you'll see what I mean exactly.

Just trying to understand what I'm doing wrong. I thought that using watcher would be reactive in the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not watching inside the child if a prop value is getting updated.
So here whenever the prop `data` changes you need to `watch` it as well in the child component.

Watch [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanketdhoble/ywaug7ft/22/),

```
watch:{
  data(val){
    this.item.gender=val.gender
  }
}
```

Or computed property [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanketdhoble/ywaug7ft/40/).

```
computed:{
  item(){
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I usually like using computed properties rather than watching, I think it's cleaner. That way you don't have to both define the calculation logic, and a magic place to store the result.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong reference: your `detail-component` receives `data` but your reference `item` in your template.

If you change the template as follows:

```
<template id="details">
   <div>
     <h4>
         <span v-if="data.gender === 3 && index === 0">Her</span>
         <span v-else-if="data.gender === 3 && index === 1">His</span>     
         <span v-else>Your</span> 
         Health Details
     </h4>
     <div>Index: {{index}}</div>
     <div>Gender: {{data.gender}}</div>
   </div>
</template>
```

it will work (see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s98qdfyw/)).

The problem here was that you somehow had gender 1 in the first detail object and therefore got "Your" instead of "Her".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by this part of your code:

```
  data() {
      return {
        item: {
          gender: this.data.gender
        }
      }
    }
```

When you assigned the value of the `gender` property from your prop into a property inside your `data()` object, it loses reference immediately. So when the `data` prop was updated, it didn't update your `item.gender`.

If your purpose is just to `alias` the gender into a variable with shorter name for ease of use, you can use [`computed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) properties which will also update every time the `data` is changed.

```
computed: {
    item() {
      return this.data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had `:v-model` in the template. But `v-model` does not take the colon. That broke everything.